# Read char from file tkinter

Tags: python, file

I need to be able to read characters (numbers) from .txt file and use them in tkinter rectangles coordinates. So basically I need to get these numbers stored in some variable to be able to work with them. Anybody?

I've tried to do this:

```
myfile = open('vystup.txt')
c = myfile.read(1)
```

which works fine but I would like to read numbers like 300, 45 and no just 3, 5, 6 etc.

my txt file looks like:

```
45 66 786 44
3 17 5 400
57 88 9 80 4
```

and the best solution will be to be able to store numbers from each row to different variable. but I suppose this should be easy anyway.

I've also found this here on stackoverflow:

```
a1 = []
a2 = []
a3 = []
a4 = []

with open('vystup.txt') as f:
    for line in f:
        data = line.split()
        a1.append(int(data[0]))
        a2.append(int(data[1]))
        a3.append(int(data[2]))
        a4.append(int(data[3]))
```

but this works for columns not rows. Anyone who can change this code to rows instead of columns?

Comment: might help to know what your txt file looks like.

Comment: also might help if you show some code, what have you tried so far etc...

Comment: try using `readline` and `split`

Comment: @Lafexlos could you be more specific? or provide any example?

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects

Comment: @Lafexlos `readline` works fine but I can't figure out how to jump to second line and how to read number until space or until coma or anything else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As [doc](https://docs.python.org/3.3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects) says:

> For reading lines from a file, you can loop over the file object. This
>   is memory efficient, fast, and leads to simple code

There is an example also about looping over file object.

Assuming your input is like

```
45 66 786 44
3 17 5 400
57 88 9 80 4
```

This code will put every number to a list. Then you can access them from those lists as you wish.

```
with open("numbers.txt") as f:
    for line in f:
        print  (line.strip().split()) #strip removes newlines and split, does splitting. 
                                      #if you give split an argument it will split  
                                      #respect to that instead of spaces

>>>
['45', '66', '786', '44']
['3', '17', '5', '400']
['57', '88', '9', '80', '4']
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to parse these values as integers, it would be useful to save these numbers as an array; let's do it this way:

```
var_array=[]
f=open('vystup.txt')
for line in f.readlines():
    # read line, split it on spaces, and append them as integers to var_array
    var_array.append(map(int,line.split()))

# now you have array of integers:
print var_array
>>> [[45, 66, 786, 44], [3, 17, 5, 400], [57, 88, 9, 80, 4]]

# having it, you can iterate through var_array 
# selecting columns needed in your code; 
# for example, get only first columns from your array:

for item in var_array:
    print item[0]

>>> 45
>>> 3
>>> 56
```

etc.

Of course I made an assumption that all the values in file are integers.